# SQL - Select latest max date when NVARCHAR column

Tags: sql, date, duplicates, max

I want to select only the latest input from my database.

Currently it always gives me all the comments even if I'm filtering using max

Simplified version of the query

```
SELECT 
    A.[Id],
    UD.[Name],
    MAX(CONVERT(DATE, AN.[PostedOn])) 'date',
    CAST(AN.[Content] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 'comment'
FROM 
    [dbo].[Account] A 
LEFT JOIN  
    [dbo].[UserData] UD ON A.[UserId] = UD.UserId
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Note] AN ON UD.[UserId] = AN.[CustomerID]
GROUP BY
    A.[Id], UD.[Name], CAST(AN.[Content] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

Current result

```
+---------+------------------------+------------+-------+
|id       |Name                    |Date        |Comment|
+---------+------------------------+------------+-------+
|01       |John                    |2017-08-15  |Blue   |
|01       |John                    |2017-07-10  |Green  |
|02       |Bob                     |2017-07-15  |Green  |
|02       |Bob                     |2017-06-05  |Red    |
|03       |Eric                    |2017-08-15  |Yellow |
|04       |Karl                    |2017-08-15  |NULL   |
|04       |Karl                    |2017-06-10  |Black  |
+---------+------------------------+------------+-------+
```

Expected/desired result:

```
+---------+------------------------+------------+-------+
|id       |Name                    |Date        |Comment|
+---------+------------------------+------------+-------+
|01       |John                    |2017-08-15  |Blue   |
|02       |Bob                     |2017-07-15  |Green  |
|03       |Eric                    |2017-08-15  |Yellow |
|04       |Karl                    |2017-08-15  |NULL   |
+---------+------------------------+------------+-------+
```

FYI If I remove `CAST(AN.[Content] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 'comment'` from my query, then I don't see 'duplicates' name/Id anymore (but no comment then)

Any idea?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, some product specifics there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT . . .,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.id ORDER BY convert(date, AN.[PostedOn]) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[Account] A LEFT JOIN
           [dbo].[UserData] UD
           ON A.[UserId] = UD.UserId LEFT JOIN
           [dbo].[Note] AN
           ON UD.[UserId] = AN.[CustomerID]
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

The `. . .` is for the list of columns that you want.

As a note:  Your query is not *filtering* by the maximum value.  Your query is calculating the maximum value using an aggregation query.  It is important to understand the difference between filtering and aggregating.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t.id, t.Name, t.date, t.Comment
FROM
(
    SELECT A.id, UD.Name, CONVERT(date, AN.[PostedOn]) AS date, t.Comment,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by t.id
                           ORDER BY CONVERT(date, AN.[PostedOn]) DESC) rn
    FROM [dbo].[Account] A
    LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[UserData] UD
        ON A.[UserId] = UD.UserId
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Note] AN
        ON UD.[UserId] = AN.[CustomerID]
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```